# How do I create a video that has seek-able timestamps from an unknown number of incoming video blobs/chunks, using ts-ebml (on-the-fly)?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, real-time, video.js, converters

I am creating a live stream component that utilizes the [`videojs-record`](https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-record/#/) component. Every `x` amount of milliseconds, the component triggers an event that returns a [blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzhoz.png). As seen, the blob contains data from the video recording. **It's not the full recording but a piece, for this got returned `x` seconds into the recording**

After saving it in the backend and playing it back, I find that I am unable to skip through the video; it's not seek-able.

Because this is a task that I'm trying to keep in the frontend, I have to inject this metadata within the browser using [`ts-ebml`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-ebml). After injecting the metadata, the modified blob is sent to the backend.

The function that receives [this blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzhoz.png) looks as follows:

```js
timestampHandler(player) {
    const { length: recordedDataLength } = player.recordedData;
    if (recordedDataLength != 0) {
        const { convertStream } = this.converter;
        convertStream(player.recordedData[recordedDataLength - 1]).then((blob) => {
        console.log(blob);
        blob.arrayBuffer().then(async response => {
            const bytes = new Uint8Array(response);
            let binary = '';
            let len = bytes.byteLength;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
            this.$backend.videoDataSendToServer({ bytes: window.btoa(binary), id: this.videoId })
        })
            .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error Converting:\t', error);
            })
        })
    }
}
```

`convertStream` is a function located in a class called TsEBMLEngine. This class looks as follows:

```js
import videojs from "video.js/dist/video";

import { Buffer } from "buffer";
window.Buffer = Buffer;

import { Decoder, tools, Reader } from "ts-ebml";

class TsEBMLEngine {
    //constructor(){
        //this.chunkDecoder = new Decoder();
        //this.chunkReader = new Reader();
    //}

    convertStream = (data) => {

        const chunkDecoder = new Decoder();
        const chunkReader = new Reader();

        chunkReader.logging = false;
        chunkReader.drop_default_duration = false;

        // save timestamp
        const timestamp = new Date();
        timestamp.setTime(data.lastModified);

        // load and convert blob
        return data.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {

            // decode
            const elms = chunkDecoder.decode(buffer);
            elms.forEach((elm) => {
                chunkReader.read(elm);
            });
            chunkReader.stop();

            // generate metadata
            let refinedMetadataBuf = tools.makeMetadataSeekable(
                chunkReader.metadatas,
                chunkReader.duration,
                chunkReader.cues
            );
            let body = buffer.slice(chunkReader.metadataSize);

            // create new blob
            let convertedData = new Blob([refinedMetadataBuf, body], { type: data.type });


            // store convertedData
            return convertedData;
        });
    }
}

// expose plugin
videojs.TsEBMLEngine = TsEBMLEngine;

export default TsEBMLEngine;
```

After recording for more than 10 seconds I stop the recording, go to the DB, and watch the retrieved video. The video is seek-able for the first 3 seconds before the dot reaches the very end of the seek-able line. When I'm watching the video in a live stream, the video freezes after the first 3 seconds.

> When I look at the size of the file in the DB, it increases after `x` seconds which means it's being appended to it, just not properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For being seekable a video (at least talking about EBMLs) needs to have a SeekHead tag, Cues tags and defined duration in Info tag.

For creating new metadata of the video you can use ts-ebml's exporting function [makeMetadataSeekable](https://github.com/legokichi/ts-ebml/blob/master/src/tools.ts#L198)

Then slice the beginning of video and replace it with new metadata like it was done in the [example](https://github.com/legokichi/ts-ebml/blob/master/src/example_seekable.ts#L133) :

```
 const decoder = new Decoder();
 const reader = new Reader();
 const webMBuf = await fetch("path/to/file").then(res=> res.arrayBuffer());
 const elms = decoder.decode(webMBuf);

 elms.forEach((elm)=>{ reader.read(elm); });
 reader.stop();

 const refinedMetadataBuf = tools.makeMetadataSeekable(reader.metadatas, reader.duration, reader.cues);
 const body = webMBuf.slice(reader.metadataSize);
 const refinedWebM = new Blob([refinedMetadataBuf, body], {type: "video/webm"});
```

And voila! new video file becomes seekable

Comment: Be mindful of posting [just] links in an answer, links [especia;;y to other sites] can break thus making the answer worthless and in general are not considered 'good asnswers'. I understand posting the code from the links may not be practical however consider if showing specific code snippets would work better here.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33491005)